# Using WebDAV to access Exchange 2003 Inbox

Tags: .net, exchange-server, webdav

How do you *(using .NET)* use WebDAV to get a listing of emails in a user's inbox (not your own inbox) and then get the properties and/or contents of each email?

I'd like to do this without [WebDAV.NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html), if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this post of mine about webdav. hopefully it should give you some pointers:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/articles/9560.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking into doing the same thing and the best solution I've come across is Henning Krause's article "[Access the Exchange store via WebDAV with Form-Based-Authentication turned on](http://www.infini-tec.de/post/2004/12/Access-the-Exchange-store-via-WebDAV-with-Form-Based-Authentication-turned-on-Updated.aspx)"

I'm about to try this, I'll let you know how it goes and I'll also check back in case you get it done first ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you didn't want to use the Independentsoft library, but we've been using this, and it makes this almost trivial. So my recommendation would be to use that. Their support is good as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Erik. We looked into Exchange/WebDAV without Independentsoft too, to start with. You can find documentation on just about everything you need, but IMO it's just not worth it - way too complicated. If this is for business purposes, there's really no question as to which is more cost-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I wanted to post a link to this answer in case any other users come across this question.  This really helped me out using .NET and WebDAV:

[Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c#answer-652729)